# How can I stop a AWS Medialive channel on input end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, streaming, live-streaming, aws-media-live

I'm using AWS Step Functions to create a channel on AWS Medialive to stream live video from S3 file to Facebook live.

I have an input of type **MP4_FILE** *(hosted in public s3 bucket)*.

**SourceEndBehavior** is set as **CONTINUE** for this **InputAttachment** for the channel.

For the **RtmpGroupSettings** in **OutputGroupSettings**, the **InputLossAction** is set as **PAUSE_OUTPUT**.

The current behavior is, the channel pauses Rtmp output on the end of playing of the provided mp4 file as input.

How can I stop the channel on the end of the input?

Comment: I am also looking for this solution. There should be some way to stop the channel so, the stream stops at the end of playing the input video.

Comment: You can stop the Channel by use of a Lambda Function, either at a set time or in response to a CloudWatch Log Message such as "PAUSE_OUTPUT" or "Video input lost" etc.   When triggered, the Lambda Function can send a 'stop-channel' call.